# Cannot allocate small memory "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Cannot Allocate 3000 bytes"

Tags: java, out-of-memory

```
public static void sendScenarioToEdc(String connectionType, String ipOrBaudrate, String portOrCom, String timeout, String profile) {
    loadEcrLib();     
    File file =  new File (ApplicationConstans.PROFILE_FOLDER +profile+ ".csv");
    // create parameter for the dll
    String param = createParameter(connectionType, ipOrBaudrate, portOrCom, timeout);
    List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
    String[] messages = CsvUtil.readRequestMessage(file);
        for (String message : messages) {

            Transaction t = new Transaction();
            t.setRequestMsg(message);
            EcrInterface ecrLib = EcrInterface.INSTANCE;
            Pointer stringMem = new Memory(3000);
            stringMem.setString(0, " ");
            Pointer response = stringMem.getPointer(0);

            // notify the user before hand
            System.out.println("Request: "+ t.getRequestMsg());
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Integer status = ecrLib.procEdcTrans(message, response, param); //send message here
            t.setResponseStatus(status.toString());
            t.setResponseTime(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);
            t.setResponseMsg(response.getString(0).replace("ÿ", ""));   // trim 0x255 characters

            System.out.println("Response: "+ t.getResponseMsg());
            System.out.println("Time: "+ (t.getResponseTime() / 1000) + "." + (t.getResponseTime() % 1000) + " s");
            System.out.println("Status: "+ t.getResponseStatus());
```

returning error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Cannot Allocate 3000 bytes

Why does the program cannot allocate such a small memory?
I have also used this parameter "java -Xmx2048m -Xms512m" for configuring the memory heap but this didn't solve the problem.

Here is the trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Cannot allocate 3000 bytes
at com.sun.jna.Memory.<init>(Memory.java:70)
at com.kartuku.utils.SenderUtil.sendScenarioToEdc(SenderUtil.java:98)
at com.kartuku.ui.Main1.btnRunMouseClicked(Main1.java:581)
at com.kartuku.ui.Main1.access$000(Main1.java:31)
at com.kartuku.ui.Main1$1.mouseClicked(Main1.java:123)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6536)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

## The program cannot allocate such a small memory for pointer stringmem

Comment: can you paste the stacktrace detail?

Comment: @naufal Put the entire error message in the question.

Comment: @HaifengZhang edited thanks

Comment: @CJBurkey edited thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means your computer is running low on memory. Try having task manager open at the same time and see what your ram usage gets to, if it gets within 3mb of full, that's the issue. If not, it's most likely Java not having enough room for the operation.

Comment: @naufal wait, 1GB is available when the program starts, or when it crashes? How much ram did the other computer have?

Comment: 1GB when it crashes

Comment: @naufal Very strange, I really have no idea, then. Does it spike at any point in time?

Comment: @naufal I've really got no clue, I'm sorry.